# Eclipse: how to launch URL with fragment?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, is there a way to launch a URL that contains fragment (`C:\...\something.html#fragment`)? Eclipse returns this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyApplication".
URI has a fragment component
```

Comment: In the Run Configurations dialog for a web project (this is a Flex project but I guess it would be very similar for WST although I don't have them installed at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

The only way that seems to work is to start a local web server and launch the URL as http://... It is a bit a of a hassle but fragments don't seem to work for local files although they are fully supported in browsers.